# Fallo en la consulta de PHP usando Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo un script en el que se realiza una consulta usando jquery, al realizarla siempre me da el mensaje de error.
Código js:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    data: {nombre : document.getElementById("nombre").value, puntos : puntos},
    url: "conexion.php",
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
    /*rank = document.getElementById("ranking");
    rank.innerHTML = data;*/
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert("Error en la consulta");
    }
});
```

Código PHP

```
@$conexion = mysqli_connect(HOST_DB, USER_DB, PASS_DB, NAME_DB);

if(!$conexion)
    die("Imposible conectar. Error n&uacute;mero ".mysqli_connect_errno().":".mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');

if(isset($_POST["nombre"])){ 

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku WHERE nombre = ".$_POST["nombre"];

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    if(!$resultado)
        die("No se ha realizado bien la consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion).":".mysqli_error($conexion));

    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    if($nums > 0){
        $arrRespuesta = array();
        //echo "El nombre indicado ya existe, prueba con otro.";
        mysqli_close($conexion); 
    }else{

        $consulta = "INSERT INTO remus_bd_sudoku (nombre, puntos) VALUES (".$_POST["nombre"].", ".$_POST["puntos"].")";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        if(!$resultado)
            die("No se ha realizado bien la consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion).":".mysqli_error($conexion));

        mysqli_free_result($resultado);

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku ORDER BY puntos";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        if(!$resultado)
            die("No se ha realizado bien la consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion).":".mysqli_error($conexion));

            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $arrRespuesta[]=$fila;
            }
        /*$pos = 0;
        $vuelta = 0;    
        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $vuelta++;
            if($fila[1] == $_POST["nombre"]){
                $pos = $vuelta;
                break;
            }
        }

        echo "Tu posición es la ".$pos;*/

        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        mysqli_close($conexion); 


    }

}

$json = json_encode($arrRespuesta);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo $json;
```

?>

Comment: El código compartido es susceptible a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas en lugar de concatenación de cadenas para formar las consultas. Eso también podría resolver otros problemas comunes con la concatenación de cadenas, como por ejemplo, no poner variables de cadena entre comillas en las sentencias SQL (otro problema del código compartido).

Comment: Lo tendré en cuenta, gracias.

Comment: Remueve el `@` antes de `$conexion`. Cambia tu consulta a esto: `$consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku WHERE nombre = '".$_POST["nombre"]."'";`

Comment: Como dice @AlvaroMontoro, deberías usar consultas preparadas para evitar el riesgo de inyección SQL. Teniendo ese punto claro, debes saber que cualquier consulta (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE) que trabaje con datos alfanuméricos debe poner esos datos rodeados por comillas simples, en cualquier parte, también en los `WHERE`. También, si la petición Ajax espera un JSON, todos los `die` que tienes debes quitarlos, **pues la petición ajax espera un json, y ¡un `die` no lo es!**. Debes recoger una respuesta lógica, por ej., un array con la clave `error` y dentro el mensaje, e imprimir ese array al final.

Comment: si hay un echo antes o un warning el formato no va a ser el indicado, verifica el en el navegador que valores te arroja el servicio

Comment: Por qué no escribes la url de tu servicio para probarlo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tu código está escrito de una forma bastante confusa. Parecería que cierra la conexión cuando todavía podrías tener necesidad de ella. No es coherente con la petición Ajax, la cual espera un JSON, imprimiendo simples mensajes con `die`. Tampoco evalúa si se postearon valores en `puntos`, pudiendo intentar la inserción de valores vacíos en ese caso.

En esta respuesta se crea un código coherente que va siguiendo los flujos del programa, agregando en cada caso contenido a un único array de salida que **será lo único que se imprimirá como un JSON**, que es lo que Ajax espera. Este es un error muy frecuente cuando trabajamos con Ajax: la incoherencia. Luego el código no funciona y tardar horas/días/semanas en averiguar por qué.

#### PHP

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect(HOST_DB, USER_DB, PASS_DB, NAME_DB);
    if(!$conexion) {
        $arrRespuesta["error"]="Imposible conectar. Error n&uacute;mero ".mysqli_connect_errno().":".mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');
        $nombre=(empty($_POST["nombre"])) ? NULL : $_POST["nombre"];
        $puntos=(empty($_POST["puntos"])) ? NULL : $_POST["puntos"];
        if($nombre && $puntos){ 
            $consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku WHERE nombre = '$nombre'";
            $resSelect = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
            if(!$resSelect){
                $arrRespuesta["error"]="No se ha realizado bien la consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion).":".mysqli_error($conexion);
            }else{            
                $nums = mysqli_num_rows($resSelect);
                mysqli_free_result($resSelect);
                if($nums > 0){
                    $arrRespuesta ["error"]= "El nombre indicado ya existe, prueba con otro.";
                }else{
                    $consulta = "INSERT INTO remus_bd_sudoku (nombre, puntos) VALUES ('$nombre',$puntos)";
                    $resInsert = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
                    if(!$resInsert){
                        $arrRespuesta["error"]="No se ha realizado bien la consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion).":".mysqli_error($conexion);
                    }else{
                        mysqli_free_result($resInsert);
                        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku ORDER BY puntos";
                        $resAll = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
                        if(!$resAll){
                            $arrRespuesta["error"]="No se ha realizado bien la consulta ".mysqli_errno($conexion).":".mysqli_error($conexion);
                        }else{
                            while ($fila = $resAll->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $arrRespuesta[]=$fila;
                            }
                            mysqli_free_result($resAll);
                        }
                    }                                
                }
            }
        }else{ 
            $arrRespuesta ["error"]="Se postearon datos vacíos";
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion); 
    }
    $json = json_encode($arrRespuesta);
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
    echo $json;
?>
```

---

#### Javascript

```
var request = $.ajax({
    data: {nombre : document.getElementById("nombre").value, puntos : puntos},
    url: "conexion.php",
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.error){
            //Elegir si mostrar en pantalla el mensaje de error o no
             console.log(data.error);
        }else{
            //Mostrar contenido normal venido del servidor 
            //Aquí conviene hacer también una lectura adecuada de data
            //y no un simple innerHTML=data ¡ ... !
            console.log(data);
            /*rank = document.getElementById("ranking");
              rank.innerHTML = data;*/
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
        alert("Error en la consulta: "+jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí solucionar el problema, eran muchas partes de l php que realizaba consultas erróneas
Código JS

```
data: {nombre : document.getElementById("nombre").value, puntos : puntos},
    url: "conexion.php",
    method: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.length == 0){
            alert("El usuario introducido ya existe, prueba con otro");
        }else{
            rank = document.getElementById("ranking");
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
               if (data[i]["nombre"] == document.getElementById("nombre").value) {
                   rank.innerHTML = "! Tu posición en el ranking es la " + i + " ¡";
               } 
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Código PHP

```
@$conexion = mysqli_connect(HOST_DB, USER_DB, PASS_DB, NAME_DB);
$arrRespuesta = array();

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, 'utf8');

if(isset($_POST["nombre"])){ 
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $puntos = $_POST['puntos'];

    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku WHERE nombre = '".$_POST['nombre']."'";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    if($nums == 0){
        mysqli_free_result($resultado);
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO remus_bd_sudoku (nombre, puntos) VALUES ('$nombre', '$puntos')";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM remus_bd_sudoku ORDER BY 'puntos'";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $vuelta = 0;
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arrRespuesta[$vuelta] = $fila;
            $vuelta++;
        }

        mysqli_free_result($resultado);

    }

}

$json = json_encode($arrRespuesta);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
echo $json;
```